# Laravel Eloquent relation for getting user name for a specific id

Tags: laravel

I have a table named `project`. In this table I have a column named `student_id`. Model for this table is `Project`. And I have another table named `user`. And model name is `User`. Now I am retrieving all `project` table details in a page including `student_id`. Now I want to show user name instead of `student_id`. I mean I want to show this student name instead of student id. For example if `student_id` is `10` then I want to print name for that user from user table whose id is `10`.

Any one please help.I have read document from laravel. But i don't know why I am not getting the eloquent concept properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define [`belongsTo()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) relationship in `Project` model class:

```
public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'student_id');
}
```

And use it:

```
$project->student->name;
```